# JQuery select based on more than one variable (specific string)

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want to create a couple if statements grabbing the ID using contains (*=) and img that equals (=).  What might I be doing wrong?

```
if($("div[id*='Point_'], [img='gray.png']").length > 0 ) {

// do something gray
}

if($("div[id*='Point_'], [img='red.png']").length > 0 ) {

// do something red
}
```

```
<div id="Point_1">
    <img src="gray.png">
</div>
<div id="Point_2">
    <img src="red.png">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried switching your quotes and double quotes around? im not sure if it matters, but the jquery pages all have double quotes around the attribute values.

Comment: @jbabey It doesn't matter, as long as you're consistent. If your overall selector is contained in double quotes, then use single quotes (or none at all, depending on the value) for your attribute values to match. If your overall selector is contained in single quotes, use double quotes. Personally, I much prefer to contain my Javascript strings in single quotes, because it makes it much easier to copy HTML into them if I ever need to (such as dynamically creating and appending DOM nodes).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i prefer single quotes as well, and thanks for the info!

Comment: @jbabey No problem. Of course, I forgot to mention that if you really wanted to you **could** use single (or double) quotes for the string and escaped single (or double) quotes (`\'` or `\"`) for the attribute values, but I can't think of any reason why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to use a tag selector like an attribute selector. If you want to match the `<img>` tag where the `src` attribute equals `gray.png` then the correct selector is `$('img[src="gray.png"]')`.

Also, this may or may not be correct for what you want to do, but the comma in a jQuery selector acts like an OR, so you're saying "Give me any `<div>` element where the `id` attribute contains the text 'Point_' OR any `<img>` element where the src matches 'gray.png'." If that's what you want, then ok.

However, it seems more likely that what you want to do is select the `<img>` element with a `src` equal to `gray.png` that is within a `<div>` with an ID containing 'Point_', so the selector should be:

```
$('div[id*="Point_"] img[src="gray.png"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to select the specific string you need to drop the comma from your string. Separating the selectors with a comma selects multiple elements based on any selector. No comma selects matching on all selectors. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).